# php/zend/json: How to fetch view then pass it as json object?

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

On the view, there is this basic javascript/jquery:

```
$('#jsoncallbtn').click(function() {
     $.post('/mycontroller/json', {
          someint: 123,
          somestr: 'string'
     }, function(datafromserver) {
          alert(datafromserver.data1); // prints "test"
          alert(datafromserver.data2); // prints "null"
     }, "json");
});
```

On server side:

```
public function jsonAction()
{
    $jsonArray = array('data1' => 'test',
                       'data2' => $this->render('anotheraction'));
    $this->_helper->json($jsonArray);
}
```

Is there a way to render another action view and send it back for javascript as part of json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the [Action View-Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action) could do the job.

Comment: It *could* do the job but there would also be a better way.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been searching for this :D

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate Zend View instance and add the view's output to the JSON array. E.g something on along the lines of:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->variable = "testing 123";
$html = $view->render('path/to/view/file.phtml');
$jsonArray["html"] = $html;
Zend_Json::encode($jsonArray);
```